# How do I use Gulp to start Jekyll in a subfolder?

Tags: jekyll, gulp

*»Hello world! How do I use Gulp to start Jekyll in a subfolder?«*

My folder structure looks like this:

```
- foundation
- jekyll
- node_modules
gulpfile.js
```

To start jekyll with gulp I use this task, which works perfect if the `gulpfile.js` is in the jekyll-folder.

```
gulp.task('jekyll', function () {
     require('child_process').spawn('jekyll', ['serve','-w'], {stdio: 'inherit'}); 
});
```

**But how do I start jekyll in the jekyll folder if `gulpfile.js` is in the root directory?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the **cwd** option to spawn did the trick :

```
gulp.task('jekyll', function () {
     require('child_process')
        .spawn('jekyll', ['serve','-w'], {stdio: 'inherit', cwd: 'jekyll' }); 
});
```

And **gulp jekyll** !

Comment: Thank you so much. What is the `cwd`standing for? Do you have a link where I can find some documentation about it? Thank you very much. This makes my gulpfile.js shine :)

Comment: See node.js doc in this case : http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options